# Sitio web adaptable a diferentes resoluciones

Tags: html5, css, css3

Realicé el diseño de un sitio web en una PC con resolución de 1600 X 900 y se mira de la siguiente manera:

[image: 1600x900]

Después lo visualice en distintos de resoluciones y se mira muy mal. Por ejemplo la siguiente imagen muestra 1366x768:

[image: 1366x768]

¿Cuál es la mejor solución para que se vea agradable en distintas resoluciones?

Comment: Voto para cerrar tu pregunta ya que se basa principalmente en opiniones.

Comment: Haz visto Bootstrap?

Comment: Échale un vistazo a  [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Si, creo que es un framework de Css.Se algunas cosas basicas de CSS y tal vez intermedias, no se si con esto pueda comenzar con Bootstrap

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo lograr que un sitio Web se vea apropiadamente tanto en "pantalla grande" como en pantalla de dispositivo móvil?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319/c%c3%b3mo-lograr-que-un-sitio-web-se-vea-apropiadamente-tanto-en-pantalla-grande-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la actualidad la mejor forma de diseño resposivo es usando librerias que lo faciliten,hay varias opciones pero quizas la mas difundida es

[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

por supuesto esto va a requerir un rediseño del sitio ya que la idea es pensar el sitio como mobile first

aqui

[bootstrap 3 youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPiMTe_552ODy1JUbwEiOaHq4gjmimBdf)

un excelente curso que creo va a introducirte en tema para que peudas diseñar de forma responsiva y las aplicaciones se adapten a diferentes resoluciones de dispositivos

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo algun framework para esto, de igual form debes tener conocimientos base, de igual forma no solo existe [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), también esta [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), de igual forma te dejo esto por aquí para le eches un ojo

- [Multiples repositorios en Github](https://github.com/showcases/design-essentials)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap es una forma fácil de hacer diseños responsivos.
Responsive = 'Agradable en en las distintas resoluciones'. Búscalo aquí: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te han señalado, [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) y [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/) son los frameworks más populares a la hora de crear sitios web de tipo "responsive", aunque no son los únicos, puedes echar un vistazo al panorama más o menos actual [aquí](http://www.awwwards.com/what-are-frameworks-22-best-responsive-css-frameworks-for-web-design.html). No obstante, si quieres "fabricar" tu propia solución responsive, será mejor que eches un vistazo a los [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Por qué el voto negativo?