# ¿Qué debo hacer cuando no me toma los media queries para móviles?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Este es mi layout

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        {!! SEO::generate() !!}
    
        <!-- FAVICON FILES -->
        
        <link href="{{ asset('netikom/images/logo-netikon-2.png') }}" rel="shortcut icon">
    
    
    
        {{-- CSS FILES --}}
        {{-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}"> --}}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('netikom/css/animate.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('netikom/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('netikom/css/odometer.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('netikom/css/fancybox.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('netikom/css/swiper.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('netikom/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('netikom/css/style.css') }}">
        {{-- JS FILES --}}
        @livewireStyles
    
        {{-- <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> --}}
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/jquery.min.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/swiper.min.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/tilt.jquery.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/wow.min.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/odometer.min.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/jquery.typewriter.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/fancybox.min.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('netikom/js/scripts.js') }}" defer></script>
    
    
    </head>
        @livewire('navigation')
    <body>
        {{ $slot }}
        @livewire('footer')
    </body>
</html>
```

Los estilos los traigo de una plantilla en css y js con html, y lo estoy adaptando a laravel 8, en el momento que integro lo que es el layout, los estilos para moviles no los toma, en movil se muestra como se ve en escritorio. Eso sucede cuando integro el codigo en el layout, porque cuando lo dejo todo directo en la pnatilla welcome.blade.php se muestra bien. Estoy utilizando Jetstream con livewire, y estoy utilizando un paquete para poder utilizar Boostrap, (Jetstrap)https://github.com/nascent-africa/jetstrap, no he podido hacer que funcione la vista en móviles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo lograr que un sitio Web se vea apropiadamente tanto en "pantalla grande" como en pantalla de dispositivo móvil?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319/c%c3%b3mo-lograr-que-un-sitio-web-se-vea-apropiadamente-tanto-en-pantalla-grande-c)

Answer (score 0):

Deberias añadir el meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

en el `<head>` del layout, para que no te haga reescalados y por lo tanto aplique bien los media-queries.

Comment: Gracias. Efectivamente quedó solucionado. No me había dado cuenta del detalle.